# Using AND in a MySQL UPDATE

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to do a MySQL Update where the code updates the database if both `FACTORY_ID` is 175 and SQUAD is `PRODUCTION_SQUAD`. The code works fine when just checking the `FACTORY_ID` but then doesn't work when I add the AND. I have tried encasing the `'SQUAD'='PRODUCTION_SQUAD'` in brackets as this is what a lot of examples are telling me to do and it is still not working.

```
mysql_query("UPDATE Drug_Factory_Thugs SET `HEALTH`='10' WHERE `FACTORY_ID`='175' AND 'SQUAD'='PRODUCTION_SQUAD'")
           or die("factory set data connect to database failled!");
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and back ticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-back-ticks-in-mysql)

Comment: Obligatory comment about `mysql_` being outdated, removed in PHP7 and insecure.

Answer (score 1):

If you put your column in `' '` Sql suppose ***there is a string in it*** . It doesn't act like a columns. So you need to change `'SQUAD'` with ``

```
mysql_query("UPDATE Drug_Factory_Thugs SET `HEALTH`='10' WHERE `FACTORY_ID`='175' AND `SQUAD`='PRODUCTION_SQUAD'")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below codes:

```
mysqli_query("UPDATE Drug_Factory_Thugs SET `HEALTH`='10' WHERE `FACTORY_ID`='175' AND `SQUAD`='PRODUCTION_SQUAD'")
           or die("factory set data connect to database failled!");
```

**Or**

```
mysqli_query("UPDATE Drug_Factory_Thugs SET `HEALTH`=10 WHERE `FACTORY_ID`=175 AND `SQUAD`='PRODUCTION_SQUAD'")
           or die("factory set data connect to database failled!");
```

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: can you explain how this code answers the question, or at least point out how it differs from the code in the question?

Comment: And why did you suddenly change API? I get that `mysql_` is outdated, but you can't just add an `i` and expect it to work